# App Engine - problemas com versão

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Estou tentando rodar uma palicação com o Google App Engine.

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Java compiler level does not
>   match the version of the installed Java project
>   facet.    Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)

As versões:

**Java**: Jre7

**AppEngine**:  1.9.34

Alguém sabe como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver utilizando o Eclipse será necessário ir em Project / Properties / Project Facets e alterar a versão do Java para 1.6 ou 1.7 e depois ir em Project / Properties / Java Compiler e alterar a versão do compilador para 1.6 ou 1.7. Provavelmente você deve estar usando a versão 1.8 do Java. Após as alterações vá em Project / Clean...